# Check php input on enter key

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am editing todo list plugin in wp , and i don't know how to make sure that empty task cannot be added on Enter key.

I have tried , but it does not work .

```
if(e.which == 0) {
                echo '<script>alert("Cannot be empty")</script>;
            }
```

Full section

```
 // check pressed keys and then do action accordingly.
        function check_key(e , ele) {
            //detect enter 




            if(e.which == 13) {
                add_new_note();
            }


            //detect backspace 
            if(e.which == 8) {
                if(jQuery.trim(jQuery(ele).val()) == '') {

                    if(jQuery('.sm_at_textarea_div').length > 1 ) {
                    jQuery(ele).closest('.sm_at_textarea_div').prev().find('input').length ) ;
```

Comment: usually enter key submits the form, why not validate on submission instead

Answer (score 0):

This line here is looking for to check if the key is null.

```
if(e.which == 0) {
    echo '<script>alert("Cannot be empty")</script>;
}
```

This is not what you're looking for. You need to validate if the `input` element's value is null or empty.

I can't see all your script but in your `add_new_note()` function, you should validate the value and then alert the error message if needed.

Something like this:

```
function add_new_note() {
  //get the value
  var value = $('#myInputfield').val();

  if (value === '') {
    alert("Cannot be empty")
  }
  else {
    //... do whatever the function already does.
  }

}
```

By the way, you seem to be mixing PHP and jQuery without any logic to it. In the line below, you're already in javascript and you're echoing a new `<script>` tag. This will give you errors.

```
if(e.which == 0) {
    echo '<script>alert("Cannot be empty")</script>;
}
```